# How to use "sudo -S" commnd in C++ to bypass terminal for password?

Tags: sudo, c++

I need to run the following command as root
without going thru any "sudo" on Linux terminal.
.
( Please refrain from "security  " comments...)

" hcitool cc address "

using "sudo -S " option should fulfill the task.

I have been given the  attached sudo / pipe code written in c.

#include 
#include 
#include

int main()
{
std::string userPass{"myPassword"};
std::string command{"sudo -S ps -lf 2>/dev/null <<_EOF\n" + userPass + "\n_EOF"};
FILE *pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t rlen;
while( (rlen = getline(&line, &len, pipe))  > 0) {
line[--rlen] = '\0'; // trim trailing newline
std::cout << line << '\n';
}

```
pclose(pipe);
free(line);
```

}

here s what I hVe so far

```
FILE  *cmd;
int    status;

QFile *pipe;

cmd = popen("/usr/bin/sudo -S id -un 2>/dev/null", "w");

// MODIFY  for c++
QString Password = "q";
QString Command =" sudo -S ps -lf 2>/dev/null <<_EOF\n" + Password + "\n_EOF";

// std::string userPass{"myPassword"};
// std::string command{"sudo -S ps -lf 2>/dev/null <<_EOF\n" + userPass + "\n_EOF"};
pipe->open ???


I could use help finishing converting the c code into C++.
```

I am using Qt , but generic C++ code would be OK.

I do not understand the "option"  "ps" - I cannot find it in man doc.
I am not sure how "cmd file" works in the example.

Thanks